# Rewriting code with useParams, deconstructuring not going well

Tags: react-router, destructuring

Trying to upgrade react router to version 5.1.
I have a problem with the useParams, the `exampleId` is not correct. I'm definatelly missing something?
My Route file with the broken `exampleId`:

```
export default function MyExample() {
  const { url } = useRouteMatch()
  const history = useHistory()
  const exampleCreateQuery = useExampleCreate()

  return (
    <>
      <Header url={url} />

      <Switch>
        <Route path={url} exact>
          
        </Route>
        
        <Route path={`${url}/:id`} children={exampleId !== undefined ? <ExampleThing exampleId={exampleId} /> : null} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  )
}
```

The route where the id comes from

```
export default function ExampleThing() {
  const { id: exampleId } = useParams<{ id: string }>()
  const exampleQuery = useExample(exampleId, { useErrorBoundary: false })
 
  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: The routes in `MyExample` should use the returned `path` from `useRouteMatch` instead of `url`. What is `exampleId` in `MyExample`? It doesn't appear to be declared. What is the issue with accessing the `id` route path param in the `ExampleThing` component?

Comment: @DrewReese I think I just figured it out. When I remove the exampleId from the Route, it somehow works.
```
<Route path={`${url}/:id`}>
        <ExampleThing/>
        </Route>
```

Comment: Was the issue that the `ExampleThing` wasn't rendered at all, or were you trying to access the `exampleId` prop, but it was undefined?

Comment: @DrewReese It wasn't rendered and the exampleId was not found.

Comment: I see. I think it's because the `Route` component expects a function on the `children` prop and you were passing JSX. Switching to wrapping the component renders it as a normal React child.